# Laravel - unexpected "}}" when using migration with entrust

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to set up Laravel with entrust on my mac, however when I run the migrate command:

```
php artisan entrust:migration
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '' }}' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)","file":"\/Users\/tom\/MAMP\/bosch-cal-admin\/admin\/app\/storage\/views\/06f59d153dac2acc0d27dd56fbb5b6e0","line":16}}
```

Reading up on potential problems I found that the issue might be that i'm running the wrong version of php in my terminal.

I have checked this and I am running:

```
PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2013 15:12:32)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v2.0.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
```

Which is supported.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Update-----
Generated code

```
{{ '<?php' }}

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class EntrustSetupTables extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Creates the roles table
        Schema::create('roles', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Creates the assigned_roles (Many-to-Many relation) table
        Schema::create('assigned_roles', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); // assumes a users table
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });

        // Creates the permissions table
        Schema::create('permissions', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Creates the permission_role (Many-to-Many relation) table
        Schema::create('permission_role', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions'); // assumes a users table
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('assigned_roles', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('assigned_roles_user_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('assigned_roles_role_id_foreign');
        });

        Schema::table('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('permission_role_permission_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('permission_role_role_id_foreign');
        });

        Schema::drop('assigned_roles');
        Schema::drop('permission_role');
        Schema::drop('roles');
        Schema::drop('permissions');
    }

}
```

Comment: Two things, first remove all cached views in `app/storage/views` and try again. Secondly, isolate the view that is erroring and put the view code in the question, this should help diagnose this problem properly.

Comment: Have tried this already, will attach the code generated by entrust.

Comment: Just replace `{{ '<?php' }}` by `<?php`

Comment: This is just generated From entrust into a temp file which then gets pulled into the migration file. I removed these {{}} but nothing is created in the migrations file. Running php artisan migrate does nothing.

Comment: removing {{ lead it to create the file but it did not move the content from the temp file into the generated class file.

Comment: remove it from the generated code!!

Comment: After further investigation, any file created by this extension in storage will not migrate properly this includes controllers. Something todo with the templating issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 4.2? Try rolling back to Laravel 4.1, the developers other package has a similar issue when using Laravel 4.2

https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/282

Comment: this actually doesn't resolve the issue, check here https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/138 for more details.